# How can i send a RsaKeyParameters to a server or vice versa?

Tags: c#, encryption, xamarin, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I am using the Bouncy Castle on Xamarin Forms to asymmectric encrypt. But i am working on a Client <-> Web Api structure. How can i send the public Key to the other side ? Because the type is RsaKeyParameters .

```
RsaKeyPairGenerator rsaKeyPairGnr = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
rsaKeyPairGnr.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 512));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = rsaKeyPairGnr.GenerateKeyPair();
RsaKeyParameters publicKey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Public;
```

Comment: `util.PublicKeyFactory`? - sorry, long day, no sense in programming anymore ;)

Comment: Use base64url, there is an RFC explaining it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I edited the post !! I got the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Better create an answer than editing it in. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have a `RsaKeyParameters publicKey` and I need to send this to a server, I can convert using:

```
//convert from key to string
SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(publicKey);
byte[] serializedPublicBytes = publicKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();    
string serializedPublic = Convert.ToBase64String(serializedPublicBytes);
And then, i can convert the serializedPublic to RsaKeyParameters publicKey

//convert from string to key
RsaKeyParameters publicKey2 = (RsaKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(serializedPublic));
```

But could someone tell me if passing the public key by querystring via Http library is a good idea ?

Comment: The main problem is that an attacker can replace the public key. You somehow need to establish trust in that public key...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes But with the Public Key he can just encrypt ! I can give it to everyone...thats the difference between sync and async crypto.

Comment: Think of it this way: there is a reason for things like certificate chains and CA's. If it were that simple, websites only had to send you their public key - no need for trusted third parties and Public Key Infrastructures. Or for PGP where you create a "web of trust". I guess you need to study key management.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes But i also implemented cipher object for OAEP to use padding !!